# Boot Error with LVM: No such file or directory

Tags: boot, grub2, mount, lvm, init

I have installed Xubuntu 20.04 encrypted on an SSD and get the following error on boot time:

```
/tmp/mountroot-fail-hooks.d//scripts/init-premount/lvm2: No such file or directory
```

The boot time is pretty slow, so I think that could be one of the reasons.

Is the reason for the error the double slash after hooks.d?

Comment: Launchpad bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools-ubuntu-core/+bug/1873797

Answer (score 0):

In my case, that was due to a misconfiguration into /etc/fstab
I previously installed Ubuntu with an encrypted HDD (LVM2) that i decided to remove (I removed the encryption and the initial partitions, not the HDD).

I had exactly the same problem (slow boot and same message).
I just removed entries from /etc/fstab about my previous partitions (that was also using mapper). And that rules.

Boot is as quick as intended now. And I modified /etc/fstab to consider my new "normal" partitions.

I bet your message and the slowness is due to a misconfiguration into /etc/fstab trying to load wrong partition.

Hope that helped.

Comment: @frabis Steps of doing "how to solve this problem" would have nice. Noob user, here.