# Can fstab be rebuilt automatically, now, in 2020?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal

My desktop fails to boot in non-recovery mode, with this error, somehow, after autoremove-ing a lot of things:

```
/tmp/mountroot-fail-hooks.d//scripts/init-premount/lvm2: No such file or directory
```

[Apparently](https://askubuntu.com/a/1241910/412701), the fix is to rebuild fstab, or something.

And [back](https://askubuntu.com/a/81729/412701) in the days of 10.04, it wasn't possible to automatically rebuild it.

How about now, in the year 2020, in the era of 20.04? And using terminal commands?

Well, it was solved by downgrading some things to update ubuntu-desktop, but that's not really answering the question...

Comment: Do you have raid turned on. Or any other rrason disk cannot br accessed

Comment: @RayWu - How would I figure that out with terminal? ... If I boot as Recovery Mode, no graphics, I can use the terminal...

Comment: Can you check if you can access to the disk through a live CD?

Comment: @RayWu - I don't have one of those? ... I can run apt update and stuff that sounds like it'd need hard disk access...

Comment: Try emptying fstab

Comment: A normal install shouldn't require it to boot

Comment: @RayWu - Blanked Fstab, rebooted... Got same error, but also now "Failed to start network name / time resolution / synchronization" ... Failed to start update utmp about system boot/shutdown", "dependency failed for update utmp about system runlevel changes" ... ... Looked at Recovery Mode's Clean... Dunno what it does, looks like it should help... Should I press it?

Comment: @RayWu - Do you mean delete fstab? Or just emptying it?

Comment: @RayWu - I recreated fstab, but that just means I'm back to square 1...

Comment: I mean empty it, not delete it. Remove all contents.

Comment: @RayWu - I did, and it caused the issues I mentioned above, so I undid it.

Comment: @RayWu - And solved, somehow, by (re)installing Ubuntu-desktop.